# Where can I find the "single most influential book" question

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I understand that the question ended up being deleted, and I understand why. I'm wondering whether the information it contained has been saved or made available elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be found on StackPrinter: http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=1711&service=stackoverflow

Anyone is free to host it themselves of course, provided they comply with [the CC-Wiki license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

If you want to participate in something similar, [Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) offers hoppin' discussion on the topic...

Answer (score 4):

It has indeed been saved across many other sites. Go to your favourite book seller of choice. Powells, Amazon.com, Fox Books, Angus & Robertson, Kinokuniya, etc.

Go to their software development section and sort by popularity or best sellers.

For the complete influence, throw in copies of *Alice in Wonderland*, *Atlas Shrugged* and *The Art of War*.

And that's the entirety of what that collation of reviews was.

Install a userscript to add "+1 Cannot leave the thunderbox without reading this" and "+1 Better than the film adaptation" comments all over the page and you'll very much have the Stack Overflow experience *thankyoucomeagain.*

Comment: Not at all.  I would like the original format back, please not the ugly stackprinter one, and I'd like a PDF without the comments. Just the book covers and the actual answers. It was a great question, and stackoverflow has gotten much worse in the years since that question lost acceptability here.

Comment: There were no actual answers. Just users posting book covers. How that is a constructive list is a strange one